# Renaming vouch-proxy http headers on k8s Ingress

Tags: nginx, http-headers, ingress-nginx

i'm trying to add a claim into the http header. i have an k8s ingress with

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://vouch.example.com/login?url=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri&vouch-failcount=$auth_resp_failcount&X-Vouch-Token=$auth_resp_jwt&error=$auth_resp_err"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://vouch.example.com/validate
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: 'X-Vouch-User, X-Vouch-Idp-Claims-Name'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
      auth_request_set $auth_resp_jwt $upstream_http_x_vouch_jwt;
      auth_request_set $auth_resp_err $upstream_http_x_vouch_err;
      auth_request_set $auth_resp_failcount $upstream_http_x_vouch_failcount;
```

and a vouch config with:

```
vouch:
  headers:
    idtoken: X-Vouch-IdP-IdToken
    claims:
    - name
```

everything works, and i can authenticate fine and i can see both my email and name under the `x-vouch-user` and `x-vouch-idp-claims-name` http headers respectively. However, i would like to map the headers to use something more appropriate.

I've tried

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Remote-User $http_x_vouch_idp_claims_name;
```

but it doesn't seem to work. what are the correct variable name(s) to use in my `proxy_set_header`?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to proxy the original OIDC ID Token to the downstream service. I was able to solve the problem with this setup...

I set the Vouch Proxy config to add the `X-Vouch-IdP-IdToken` header:

```
vouch:
  headers:
    idtoken: X-Vouch-IdP-IdToken
```

Then in the ingress-nginx annotations, I was able rename the `X-Vouch-IdP-IdToken` to `Authorization` by adding the `auth_request_header` setting in the [`configuration-snippet`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation to the following:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      auth_request_set $auth_resp_x_vouch_idp_idtoken $upstream_http_x_vouch_idp_idtoken;
      proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $auth_resp_x_vouch_idp_idtoken";
```